# Trying to run Puppeteer and getting an error Could not find Chrome (ver. 118.0.5993.70)

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

new to coding so please excuse if this makes little sense.  I have created a .js program that uses Puppeteer.  It is working fine on my PC but when I try to run it on my laptop I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Coding\Projects\Websscraper\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\ProductLauncher.js:298
                    throw new Error(`Could not find Chrome (ver. ${this.puppeteer.browserRevision}). This can occur if either\n` +
                          ^

Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 118.0.5993.70). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: C:\Users\andre\.cache\puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Coding\Projects\Websscraper\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\ProductLauncher.js:298:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Coding\Projects\Websscraper\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\ChromeLauncher.js:204:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Coding\Projects\Websscraper\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\ChromeLauncher.js:97:37)
    at async ChromeLauncher.launch (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Coding\Projects\Websscraper\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\ProductLauncher.js:79:28)
    at async Timeout.scrapeData [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Coding\Projects\Websscraper\PuppetterAttempt2.js:51:19)

Node.js v20.7.0
```

I have made sure Puppeteer is intsalled.  Checked the Package.Json (see below) and I have updated chrome to the latest version

```
{
  "name": "websscraper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "node-notifier": "^10.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "open": "^9.1.0",
    "pupeteer": "^0.0.1",
    "puppeteer": "^21.4.1",
    "twilio": "^4.19.0"
  }
}
```